# Show $A$ and $B$ are invertible if $\|\alpha AB - I \|<1$

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, inverse

Here is a question from a past upper-level linear algebra problem set I came across:

> Show $A$ and $B$ are invertible if $\|\alpha AB - I \|_F<1$ for some
> $\alpha$, a scalar (here, $\|\cdot\|_F$ denotes the frobenius Norm).
> Moreover, can another norm be used? (ie, schatten, operator norm or otherwise).

I am unsure of how to proceed. I know that if $C=\alpha AB - I $ then
$$S=I+C+C^2+...\to (I-C)^{-1}=(2I-\alpha AB)^{-1}$$

But of course this to me doesn't provide any information about the matrices $A$ and $B$ on their own. From my intuition, I would also guess that the Gershgorin circle theorem may be helpful to prove that the eigenvalues are sufficiently far from $0$, but I can't seem to make that work.

Thank hints are helpful.

Comment: it suffices to prove $AB$ is invertible.

Comment: Can you elaborate?

Comment: If $ABv=0$ then $\|(\alpha AB-I)v\| = \|v\|$.

Comment: Oh I see so you choose $v$ to be a unit eigenvector?

Comment: There is an immediate contradiction.

Comment: Note that $\|\alpha A B -I\|_2 \le \|\alpha A B -I\|_F$.

Answer (score 1):

*Hints.* Since Frobenius norm is unitarily invariant, if $AB$ is singular, we may assume that it is an upper triangular matrix whose first column is zero. Now show that $\|\alpha AB-I\|_F\ge1$.

Alternatively, if $AB$ is singular, let $u$ be a unit vector in its null space. Now consider $\|(\alpha AB-I)(uu^\ast)\|_F$. Use the submultiplicativity of Frobenius norm and the given condition to see how contradiction arises.